# jquery + ie8: backspace not being detected?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I want to disable backspace in one of my inputfields so I wrote the following jquery:

```
$("#noBackspacesHere").keypress(function(e){
            if(e.which == "8"){
                return false;
            }
        });
```

This works fine in firefox, but doesn't seem to work in ie8.
I've already read that .keyCode has issues so that's why I went for .which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just played around with the keyboard events and `keydown` will help you here:

```
$("#noBackspacesHere").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 8) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/7xBRf/

I did `typeof(e.which)` and it said that it's a number, so you don't need the quotes around it. I've tested this in IE8, Chrome and FF and it seems to work for them.

Comment: Correct, oddly enough, Backspace does not trigger a keypress event in IE.

Comment: Thank you, pretty amazed that backspace doesn't trigger a keypress event in IE.

Answer (score 3):

@Jonathon Bolster's code doesn't work for Opera.

This should work in Opera, IE, FF and Chrome.

```
$("#noBackspacesHere").bind("keypress keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 8) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Also, `e.which` is the preferred way to check for key codes because jQuery normalizes the event object so that `which` will always be present no matter what browser you use.

Comment: Indeed. Why do you add the e.preventDefault() though? Since you use return false that seems redundant since false has that functionality + stopPropagation?

Comment: I have never liked the "return false" method, it feels hackish, although valid. PreventDefault feels more polished, and I think it might have other positive effects. To your question, use one or the other, the redundancy here is not needed

Comment: @jack: That's a good question and after looking it up I realized that I've been using it incorrectly. Using `e.preventDefault();` continues execution past that line to the end of the function. My intention with `return false;` was to stop the function from continuing, however, according to [this](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/) and what you've said, it stops propagation as well as preventing default behaviour. I was unaware that jQuery handled that like that. So, yeah, in this case you don't need `return false;`.